# Python: Mac Os error importing statistics module

Tags: python, macos, module, statistics

I was working with Visual Studio Code on windows and wanted to try in Mac Os, installed succesfully VSCode but at the time of trying to import the statistics module an error says that: No module named statistics found.

```
import math
import statistics as st

mean = st.mean(0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6)
print(mean)
```

Comment: `math` is import but it is never used in your code?

Comment: Not at this time, I was trying to go further in the code but error in statistics module stops me.

Comment: your problem in using the mean function

Comment: File "/Users/oto/Desktop/VS Code Samples/Stat_01.py", line 3, in <module>
    import statistics as st
ImportError: No module named statistics
Macintosh:VS Code Samples oto$

Comment: The `mean` function  take list not individual values

Comment: `statistics` should be a built-in module in any recent version of python.  What version are you using?  You can run this code to see `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: At the bottom in the VS Code says Python **3.12.0** but after running your code says that **2.7.5**, how can I switch to the newer one?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing might be related to how you are using the `mean` function.

The [`mean`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-statistics-mean-function/) function expects an iterable (like a list or tuple) as an argument, not individual values.

Here's the corrected code:

```py
import statistics as st
data = [0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6]
mean = st.mean(data)
print(mean)
#0.66
```

Comment: Oh, yes but my terminal wont go further, this is the error its giving me:   File "/Users/oto/Desktop/VS Code Samples/Stat_01.py", line 3, in <module>
    import statistics as st
ImportError: No module named statistics
Macintosh:VS Code Samples oto$

Comment: @OtonielRamirez yes because the mean function take list not individual values  have you tried my code?

Comment: Yes I did, and the same error message is appearing

Comment: @OtonielRamirez Can you run this command `pip install statistics` in your terminal and try again ?

Comment: I have tried that out: Macintosh:VS Code Samples oto$ pip3 install statistics
Requirement already satisfied: statistics in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (1.0.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from statistics) (0.20.1)

Comment: @OtonielRamirez run this command in your terminal `python /Users/oto/Desktop/VS\ Code\ Samples/Stat_01.py`

Comment: Same thing: Last login: Fri Nov 10 17:13:10 on console
Macintosh:~ oto$ python /Users/oto/Desktop/VS\ Code\ Samples/Stat_01.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oto/Desktop/VS Code Samples/Stat_01.py", line 3, in <module>
    import statistics as st
ImportError: No module named statistics
Macintosh:~ oto$